# How to change selected listview row color in android?

Tags: android, listview, background, simpleadapter

I have generated a `Listview` using `SimpleAdapter`. I want to change the background color of the row on click to black. when I had only one row in the Listview the background color set  to black. but when i have more than one row in my Listview even if I click the first row the last row's color changes to black. can anyone suggest any solution to this?
My codes are as follows:

```
    public class mycontacts extends Fragment {
     @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycontacts_activity, container,
            false);
       SimpleAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.contact2,new String[]{"name","path","id"},new int[]{R.id.example_itemname,R.id.path,R.id.contactid})
    {

          @Override
            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            { 

                final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                final RelativeLayout l=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.front);
               swipy.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener(){

          @Override
        public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onClickFrontView(position);
        l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
           });


                return v;
            }
    };
            swipy.setAdapter(k);


    return view;

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom adapter for the ListView in your case. You can make one by extending the BaseAdapter class. Have a look at this tutorial

[tutorial about custom adapter](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)

You can basicaly asign an `OnClickListener` to every view in the `getView()` method.

The OnClickListener:

```
private class ItemClick implements OnClickListener{
  public void onClick(View v){
     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
  }
}
```